# Make private computer's IP accessible by server

Tags: networking, apache-http-server, proxy, ip, tunnel

To say it in other words: My computer has an IP address 1.1.1.1 and the server has an IP address 2.2.2.2. My computer can access the server's IP 2.2.2.2 and work with services running on its ports (Apache, SOCKS proxy etc.). But the server can't do the same with my computer - my ISP doesn't allow it - it means when I run an Apache service on my computer on port 80, the server isn't able to call 1.1.1.1:80 (the call won't pass ISP's firewalls and reach my computer).

So, is there a way (but not contacting the ISP) to allow the server to call my IP address with successful response?

I mean creating some sort of "tunnel" which my computer opens to the server and makes the computer's IP accessible through the tunnel.

Comment: Are you sure your ISP is blocking this? Isn't it just a matter of setting up your NAT (router) properly?

Answer (score 0):

You're not telling much about your setup beyond assumed example IP's and server software so I'm making a bit of assumptions and guesses here.

Make sure it actually is your ISP that is blocking the inbound port 80 as that can be done on modems/firewalls locally too. If you have, for example, ADSL modem serving you the connection it just might be the modem that's doing the blocking and in that case you might be able to open up the port depending on the configuration modem has. Same with cable modems.

If your ISP is actually blocking port 80 for inbound traffic there isn't much else you can do besides using a tunnel of sorts. I don't know if any VPN providers allow such possibility, but you could in theory utilize friends computer (though I do not recommend this) and route inbound traffict to port 80 from there to your computer through VPN or if you have access to external server or VPS provider you could route traffic from over there to your computer assuming you can keep VPN connection open for this.

Now keep in mind, though, that some ISP's especially forbid usage of servers in their consumer networks. This could cause problems if it's mentioned in the contract you have with them.

As for how to create VPN or tunnel of sorts, that depends a lot on what operating system you're using. With Windows I've used putty for tunneling, but there are better options available, I just fail to remember names. As for creating VPN, OpenVPN is decent option.

I'm also assuming that the IP addresses you're using in your question are just examples and not actual IP addresses you're using in your network as this could cause problems with the external network (Internet).